# Are there any security issues if I open a port for public on my AWS EC2 for running slackbot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, slack

I am making a Slackbot on my AWS EC2, and I need to open port 3000 for public to listen post requests from Slack whenever users do some actions because Slack doesn't provide their IP range.

I wonder if there are any security issues with my EC2 if I open a port publicly ? I also use this EC2 to run Airflow.

Comment: If this is a production app it would be ideal to have a lambda function verify the requests from slack and then forward to the EC2 instead of opening the port to public. https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack

Comment: Yes, it's a production app. I think your solution is reasonable. I will try it. But I still want to know opening a port can cause any security issues ? :)

Comment: Yes there is security risk to open a port to public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open ports can be dangerous when the service listening on the port is misconfigured, unpatched, vulnerable to exploits, or has poor network security rules.
2. Attackers use open ports to find potential exploits. To run an exploit, the attacker needs to find a vulnerability.
3. AWS works on Shared Responsibility Model - means AWS is responsible for “Security of the Cloud”  and Customer is responsible for “Security in the Cloud”

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to put your EC2 instance in the private subnet and place a load balancer in the public subnet.

The public internet traffic shall only talk to the load balancer rather than the instance itself.

Then you can create a WAF and attach it to the load balancer to avoid the attack ( such as DDoS etc.)